Wanting to create a cut-off point for measurement (Length by width) at which an adverse outcome occurs
I am working on a project investigating dimensions of tears in shoulders and how it affects retear rate after an operation.
From the literature, age, and tear size (Dimensions AP [width], ML [length], area [AP x ML]) are correlated with outcomes.
I am looking at different groups based on the number of anchors used to hold down the tear. The general idea is that very small tear sizes can use one anchor, and larger tear sizes can use more anchors.
My goal is to find the cutoff point at which dimensions (AP x ML) for which using a single anchor is equal to using multiple anchors.
The data I have is quite skewed towards the multiple anchors: n=200 for single anchor, and n=1000 for multiple anchors.
If we look at medium sized tears (ML<=30mm), we get like n=200 for single anchor and n= 600 for multiple anchors.
What I did previously was use propensity score matching on SPSS to match based on a few variables - age, tear size ML, AP, tear area (AP x ML), and gender. I did Chi square comparisons for retear rate by the tear sizes into ML<=10, and ML11-30mm and each subgroup into AP<=10mm and AP 11-30mm.
This was based on previous research that created these categories.
However I was wondering if there was a way to determine a cutoff point, like with ROC curves. However what I am looking for is values when the single anchor group are comparable to the multiple anchors group. I imagine there would be a way to do this with regression, or perhaps a technique I am missing.
TL;DR - treating to identify a cutoff point for variables at which the outcome in one group is comparable to the outcome of another.
